# Unable to sharing image file with other app using FileProvider

Tags: android, image, android-intent, uri, fileprovider

I have image list and I want to share image that selected.To do, I have used **FileProvider**. I'm running app on **Android 10**. Also I have tried without shareIntent(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri), then app opening only share via dialogs.After not sharing anything just returning the app.

in AndroidManifest.xml;

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

in paths;

```
<paths>
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="/" />
<cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="/" />
```

here is the how I used and start intent,

```
 int pos = getAdapterPosition();

 File imageFile = new File(imageQuotes.get(pos).getPath());
 Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", imageFile);

 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
 shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
 mContext.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

When run the app,after I have choosed WhatsApp for ie. My image file sent as a BIN file and not has image preview on whatsapp.
uri is not null and is *content://com.scoto.partestestapplication.provider/files/SavedImageQuotes/Partes_1601815401590*

Comment: Please tell the value of `imageQuotes.get(pos).getPath()` as we dont know which file path that would be.

Comment: `My image file sent as a BIN file and not has image preview on whatsapp. ` What do you mean with as BIN file? And why should there be a preview? And what is the problem exactly? That preview?

Comment: value of `imageQuotes.get(pos).getPath()` is _ /data/user/0/com.scoto.partestestapplication/files/SavedImageQuotes/Partes_1601815401590_ and value of `uri.toString` is _content://com.scoto.partestestapplication.provider/files/SavedImageQuotes/Partes_1601815401590_

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Can you share or not? Choose an email app to share your image. What happens?

Comment: Use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard. It is your image, so it is your job to state what the MIME type is.

Comment: like [link](https://ibb.co/JBQNHP8)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have left a link previous comment. the problem is even I have sent image on whatsapp, not sending image, I think it's a binary file not image.  that's is the actual problem.

Comment: I have solved. Thanks your attention. The problem was saving an image file. I was saving image without extension. Then I have added with ".jpg" extension. So it's working.

Comment: Hard to believe. Not here. With or without extension does not matter.